# Can i remove artisan package:dicover from a laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm facing an intermitent issue with laravel and i would like to know if you guys already faced the same issue and how did you solve it.

My app was developed using docker and when i deploy it to review on gitlab, there's a series of jobs that run to get the app running on AWS.

It's all fun and games, untill "artisan package:discover --ansi" get's stuck for 3 minutes and npm also decides to have it's go and freezes everything for like 10 minutes.

In my case, since i'm using laravel as an API and have no view's I know i can remove NPM from the equation.

But how about artisan package:discover? Can i remove it?

Comment: just don't call it ... it is probably only being called because it is in the "scripts" part of the `composer.json` file, you don't "need" any of those, you can run any of this stuff yourself when needed

Comment: It worked with no problems. Thanks for taking the time to asnwer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Guess i should have tested it before posting here.

Just removed the line on the scripts section com composer.json as indicated by @lagbox and it worked flawlesly.

Thanks!